# UIDatePicker.date bug

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker

I'm having a problem getting the date from UIDatePicker. I know the code of getting the date, but it just keeps on getting the CURRENT date, not the date form the picker.

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)sender {

NSDateFormatter *formate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];

NSDate *settedDate = self.myPickedDate.date;
[formate setDateFormat: @"dd.MMM.yyyy @ HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *dateString = [formate stringFromDate:settedDate];
NSLog(@"datestring: %@", dateString);
}
```

I set myPicker to 15th May 2015 15:30 and Xcode logs out the current date (if it's 16:19 he will log out 22nd.Apr.2015 16:19, no matter what.

Xcode 5.1.1 on simulator iOS 7.1.2 (haven't tried on real device).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your `viewDidLoad` you are saying this:

```
self.myPickedDate = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
```

So, think about that code. What you are doing there is creating a *new* date picker, completely *different* from the one in your interface, and *substituting* it for the one in your interface, to which `self.myPickedDate` was previously set (because it is an outlet). So from now on, `self.myPickedDate` refers to a *different* date picker, one that is *not* in your interface (it is merely held in memory)! Therefore, nothing you do in the interface, such as setting the date in the date picker you see there, has any effect on `self.myPickedDate`.

Therefore, to solve the problem, **delete that line of code**.